# Use wp_remote_get() with a private or password protected page?

Tags: cron, wp-remote-get

Is there any way to use the wp_remote_get() function to access a WordPress page that is either set to Private -OR- password protected (using the native password option in the post visibility settings)? The page I need to access is on the same site.

I am using this function in a cron event to access this page, but I don't want this page to be accessible by the public or search bots. Googlebot is ignoring my "noindex" on the page.

Thank you!

Comment: Where is this psge? Is it on the same site? Or someone elses site? Is there a reason you aren't using the REST API if you're fetching the post using code?

Comment: It is the same site. I need to load the page to make a shortcode run. The shortcode needs to be on a page, rather than using do_shortcode in the function (long story), so I have to just load the page. wp_remote_get() is what I've been using and it worked, but I'll use whatever method will work to load the page while protected or private.

Comment: This sounds massively over-complicated, I'm unsure what your shortcode actually does. What's the original problem that lead to all of this? Is this a shortcode that lets you embed another page inside a post? If this request is being made to the same site then there is zero reason to be making any kind of HTTP request at all, none whatsoever. I can guarantee there is a better/simpler/faster method but I need to know what you were originally trying to do identify specifically what you should do instead to write an appropriate answer